# Regex to only choose one of the defined characters are allowed

Tags: regex

I have arrays of characters which is [-_.]. And I want to make a rule to only choose one of those characters to appear in the string. So if it's already using -, then _ and . are not allowed.

For example.

1. google-facebook = OK
2. google--facebook = OK
3. google____facebook = OK
4. google_-facebook = ERROR
5. google._facebook = ERROR

Need help to build a correct regex for these conditions. For now my current form is
`^[a-z-A-Z0-9_.]$`

**Update**

-_. cannot be at the beginning or end of string

More examples

1. google-facebook_twitter = ERROR
2. google-facebook-twitter = OK
3. youtube-instagram.tiktok = ERROR
4. youtube.instagram.tiktok = OK

Comment: looks like you need an OR operation

Comment: - and _ are only allowed in the middle or are they allowed in the beginning and end as well?

Comment: they are not allowed

Comment: Does my answer solve the issue?

Comment: for the previous example is yes, but I already update the description to include more examples that I forgot to mention before @WiktorStribiżew , but thank you for your answer, they are helpful too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?=([-_.]?))(?:\1+[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jb7Ocq/2).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` - one or more letters/digits
- `(?=([-_.]?))` - a positive lookahead (when the regex engine tries its pattern, the regex index remains where it was in the string) that captures (if present) the next `-`, `_` or `.` into Group 1
- `(?:\1+[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*` - zero or more occurrences of

  - `\1+` - one or more occurrence of Group 1 value
  - `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` - one or more letters/digits
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: May I ask why you opted for optional/repeating non-capture groups?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus All the examples start and end with an alphanumeric char.

Comment: Yes, but wouldn't `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+([-_.])\1*[a-zA-Z0-9]+$` suffice per the examples given? I'm not seeing any information which would lead me to believe that `google-facebook.instagram` exists nor that it would be valid.

Comment: Ditto for the existence or validity of just `google`

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Sorry, this is how I got the problem. If you think it should be addressed another way, please post your solution, close as a duplicate, and so on.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I already update the description to include more examples, now I am playing around with your answer to cover the new examples

Comment: @Roy This is not a problem, use `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?=([-_.]?))(?:\1+[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jb7Ocq/2).

Comment: Wow nice this is what I am looking for, thanks @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew, do you know how to convert this to golang regex?

Comment: @Roy Yes, `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:(?:-+[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*|(?:_+[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*|(?:\.+[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)$`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jb7Ocq/4).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew wow, you are really a regex master! thank you so much :D